# Why did Paz leave A Perfect Circle

Tags: a-perfect-circle, band-members

Paz Lenchantin was the original bassist for A Perfect Circle on the Mer De Noms album. However, she was replaced by Jeordie White for Thirteenth Step. What led to this change in lineup? Did Paz leave for her own reasons, or was she booted out of the band?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Thirteenth Step's wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Step#Writing_and_recording) it appears that Paz left A Perfect Circle for her own reasons, because she was joining [Zwan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwan). In [this MTV interview](http://www.mtv.com/bands/a/a_perfect_circle/news_feature_030929/index3.jhtml) Billy Howerdel states that *"she wanted to be in a band that was constantly active, and whenever Keenan was on the road with Tool, a Perfect Circle were in limbo*".